# Approximate covariance of a uniform closure

Tags: variance, covariance, uniform-distribution

I am interested to find a formula for approximate covariance of a uniform closure U(0,1)/summation{U(0,1)} for n independent U(0,1). I could derive an approximate expression for the variance = 1/(3n^2) for large n. I am interested in something similar for the covariance term.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Call 
$$ V_j = \frac{U_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n U_i}$$

$$ \sum_{j=1}^n cov( V_1, V_j) = cov (V_1, 1) = 0$$
Then

$$\frac{1}{3n^2} \approx Var(V_1) = -\sum_{j=2}^n Cov(V_1, V_j)$$

Finally convince yourself that for all $i, j$
$$cov(V_i, V_j) = cov(V_1, V_j)$$